# Keep particular tag td always visible when scrolling

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-position, visible

This is my table in Html:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    <table>
        <tr>
          <th >Header A</th>
          <td style="position:absolute; " >col 1 - A</td>
          <td >col 2 - A (COVER CONTENT)</td>
          <td >col 3 - A</td>
          <td >col 4 - A</td>
          <td >col 5 - A</td>
          <td >col 6 - A</td>
          <td >col 7 - A</td>
          <td >col 8 - A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Header B</th>
          <td >col 1 - B</td>
          <td>col 2 - B</td>
          <td>col 3 - B</td>
          <td>col 4 - B</td>
          <td>col 5 - B</td>
          <td>col 6 - B</td>
          <td>col 7 - B</td>
          <td>col 8 - B</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Header C</th>
          <td>col 1 - C</td>
          <td>col 2 - C</td>
          <td>col 3 - C</td>
          <td>col 4 - C</td>
          <td>col 5 - C</td>
          <td>col 6 - C</td>
          <td>col 7 - C</td>
          <td>col 8 - C</td>
        </tr>

    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
<style>

table {
  table-layout: fixed; 
  width: 100%;
  *margin-left: -100px;/*ie7*/
}
td, th {
  vertical-align: top;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding:10px;
  width:100px;
}
th {
  position:absolute;

  left:0; 
  width:100px;
}
.outer {position:relative}
.inner {
  overflow-x:scroll;
  overflow-y:visible;
  width:400px; 
  margin-left:100px;
}
</style>
```

I worked good when keeping tag `<th>` freezing, but I want to keep visible tag `<td>` with content "col 1 - A" by adding `style="positon:absolute;"` into `<td>` tag. it keep but the content of the other `<td>` cover it, that means "col 2 - A (COVER CONTENT)" and "col 1 - A" cover each other in the same cell.

p.s.: If I have tag `<td rowspan="2">` how do I set position:absolute in this tag? I tried to add it into `<td>` but it just keep only one row....
Need help....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<td ><div style="position:fixed;background-color: white;width:inherit" >col 1 - A</div></td>
```

Here is demo: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bhimubgm/cnW7V/)

Comment: thanks, but could you give me the way filling background-color all the cell? its only cover apart of the cell.....